# Responsive device type targeting

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

All,

I am trying to develop a responsive site, but for some reason the media query I use for the ipad/tablet is also effecting the iphone/mobile. Are my dimensions wrong?

What is the best way to target all three device types?

Thanks

/*desktop*/
@media (min-width:1100px)

/*ipad*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1115px)

/*iphone*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in responsive design and there are many approaches that try to solve it. I myself find a 4-breakpoint layout to be the most fitting for most of the situations.

**Phone:** default
**Phone-Landscape:** min-width 480px;
**Tablet:** min-width 768px
**Tablet-Landscape:** min-width 1024px
**Desktop:** min-width 1260px

Answer (score 1):

Think of `min-width` as meaning **greater than or equal to** and think of `max-width` as meaning **less than or equal to**.

By that logic your iPad rules (less than or equal than 1115px) are also going to affect the iPhone since it's screen **is** less than 1115px.

It sounds like you want to use an `AND` on your ipad rule to make it only affect rules that are bigger than your iphone rule set.  Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1115px) and (min-width: 768px)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries for more information